# Exit loop unless input not given

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
int main()
{
string name;
while(cin>>name)
{
    if(name=='\n')
       break;
    else
    {
        cout<<name;
    }
}
cout<<"Exited";
}
```

Here I need to get input till the user didn't give input or skips with the new line. I am unable to complete the code.

Comment: you should use `getline`

Comment: Yes, and `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @appleapple Are you saying like this  while(getline(name)){}

Comment: And turn on a high warning level in your compiler: `..\main.cpp:10:21: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]` `if (name == '\n')`

Comment: For proper use of `getline`, see the documentation and example code here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thisngs to watch:

1. Lets add the correct headers.
2. Lets not do the `using namespace std;` as it causes problems.
3. Let use `getline()` rather than `operator>>` so we can see a whole line
4. Lets use `std::string` rather than a `C-array` of char.
5. Can check for empty line as part of the while test.
6. Lets add `'\n'` so we can see the output.
7. Lets do some nice formatting.

Result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, name) && name != "")
    {
        std::cout << name << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Exited\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new line character `'\n'` is a white space character that by default is skipped by the operator >> for the input stream. Instead use for example member function `getline`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char name[30];

    while ( std::cin.getline( name, sizeof( name ) ) && name[0] )
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Exited\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code 
First of all you cant put " cin >> name " in while condition 
it's completely wrong .

you have arrays of characters ( name [30])
and then you want to compare it with user's input , in you didn't declare the array so its wrong

then again in your next condition name == '\n' is not valid for what you want 
in our cmd console we can only put a characters you can't use '\n'

in the end of main function you have to return something (maybe its confusing )
just write "return 0;" in the end and it will be OK
i recommend you using this code::

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char name[30];
    while(1)
    {
        cin >> name;
        if( name[0] =='E')
           break;
        else
        {
            cout<<name;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Exited";


        return 0;
    }
```

if user enter 'E' character , if conditions becomes true and we exit while.

Comment: Unbounded input extraction to a char* is also a serious problem in the code. **Don't do that.**

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
    getline( std::cin, name );
    if (!std::cin or name.empty())
      break;
    // do stuff with name here
  }
  std::cout << "Exited\n";
}
```